# Apache CXF: including installed jar with apache cxf dependencies to project with web-service

Tags: maven, cxf, soap-client

Last days I'm struggling with this problem.
I've developed a apache cxf service.
I've made a client jar and install it to maven repository.
I've include it to my project with scope test for integrations test.
But when I run my tests I am getting this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:279)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:281)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:238)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:182)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'espProjectPolicyCounterSoapService' defined in class path resource [com/rsa/eosago/platform/config/apachecxf/EspApacheCxf.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'espProjectPolicyCounterSoapService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.util.ClassHelper.getRealClass(Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:766)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:819)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'espProjectPolicyCounterSoapService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.util.ClassHelper.getRealClass(Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.util.ClassHelper.getRealClass(Lorg/apache/cxf/Bus;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getImplementorClass(EndpointImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:403)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:338)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)
    at com.rsa.eosago.platform.config.apachecxf.EspApacheCxf.espProjectPolicyCounterSoapService(EspApacheCxf.java:77)
    at com.rsa.eosago.platform.config.apachecxf.EspApacheCxf$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f50bba27.CGLIB$espProjectPolicyCounterSoapService$3(<generated>)
    at com.rsa.eosago.platform.config.apachecxf.EspApacheCxf$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f50bba27$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2b3306ee.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at com.rsa.eosago.platform.config.apachecxf.EspApacheCxf$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f50bba27.espProjectPolicyCounterSoapService(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

But if I comment my dependencies

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-wadl2java-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

in my jar soap client - all is ok.
I'm using Spring-boot last version without xml.

Update:
Ok, thank you all. I've solved it replacing all apache cxf dependencies in jar soap client by following:

```
<!-- apache cxf client-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

As I understand it's the only dependencies needed for apache cxf as client.

Comment: This error occus when multiple versions of Apache CXF are used. Can you post the result of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @user2153635, make your update the answer (and accept it when you can).  Nice work.

Comment: To second @user944849, you really should take the edited part of your question where you show your solution, out of your question, and post it as an answer and accept it.  If you do, I will upvote it.  :)